# DVWP - pass rowId to child joined subview

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a DVWP in Sharepoint Designer displaying list of answers from a quiz (list items). This is a joined subview to load the corresponding question from another list into the answer row.

From each answer row, how do I go about passing its corresponding rowId to a secondary joined subview? I can't seem to access the rowId of the parent from within the child.

Basically I'm attempting to make the child in each row load a list of possible answers to the parent question.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using web part connections.  If you created custom data views, you would need to hook up the connections interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx).  Note that web part connections only work on web part pages - they don't work on wiki pages.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this from within the same web part? Each row has an ID by default, all that is needed is for the parent row listing to pass its ID in column A in dvt_1 to the child lookup in column X dvt_2. An inner join of sorts.